# Atomics WITHOUT C++11 support?

Tags: c++, c++11

For backwards compatibility reasons, we need to support versions of C++ prior to C++11, so we cannot use `std::atomic<...>`. However, we still need atomics.

Is there an alternative to `std::atomic<...>` that's possible in previous versions of C++?

Preferably without including any new dependencies, but I realize this might be impossible.

EDIT: we need this specifically for Unix and Xbox360. We have considered Boost but don't want such a large depeundency for one platform that we will upgrade to C++11 in a few years.

Comment: Before c++11 there were a lot of platform dependent ways to do this. So telling us your supported platforms may help answer.

Comment: It is a dependency but boost comes with a thread library.

Comment: "we need to support versions of C++ prior to C++11" - I *truely* pitty you. Is there really *no way* you can move forward from a decade+ old language (C++03)?

Comment: Atomics are *meaningless* in C++98, because threads can't exist. Since you're obviously limited by a specific ancient compiler, look up that compiler's documentation, and be aware that, in general, only `seq_cst` is available.

Comment: Jesper, we are planning on it, but one of our platforms doesn't support C++11 at all, so we can only move on once that platform is gone, which will take a few more years. Our other platforms have been slow to upgrade since we can't take full advantage of C++11 while some platforms don't use it.

Comment: Regarding your edit: Most of boost's thread library is the basis for the standard thread library so you should be able to switch from it to C++11+ with not a lot of maintenance.

Comment: I can answer the 360 question as I used to program there. The platform specific way there is to us `volatile int v;` (yes volatile, never use volatile in modern codebase for threadsafety but thats how we rolled back then). And then use `InterlockedIncrement`, `InterlockedDecrement`, `InterlockedCompareAndSwap` and any other `Interlockedxxx` functions which the Xdk supplies you.

Comment: @n.m. thanks for the advice but I quite like it here. The main reason we need to support older C++ is for XBox360, which we're planning dropping support for.  There's nothing we can really do about the fact that the 360 doesn't have a C++11 compiler.

Comment: It is my impression that boost doesn't support real (hardware-based, not emulated) atomics outside of a few popular compilers and platforms, see filenames in boost/atomic/detail/ and `thread_fence` implementations in them.

Answer (score 0):

GCC has this builtin support of atomic
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html